# [DRF]What are the benefits of using nested Serializers over separate resources?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, nested

plz someone let me know what the benefits of a nested serializer are with using it non-seperated apis(In other words, one api and same with not seperated resources)?

FYI, I'm trying to make 3 nested serializer for create and update methods.
Many parts are omitted, but the my picture is as follows.

```py
# models.py
class Foo(Model):
    title = CharField(...)

class Bar(Model):
    foo = ForeignKey("Foo", ...)

class Bar2(Model):
    bar = ForeignKey("Bar", ...)
```

```py
# serializers.py
class Bar2WriteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_date):
        ...
    def update(self, instance, validated_date):
        ...

class BarWriteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    bar2 = ListField(
        child=Bar2WriteSerializer(),
        ...
        )
    def create(self, validated_date):
        ...
        bar2_serializer = self.fields["bar2"].child
        bar2_serializer.create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_date):
        ...
        bar2_serializer = self.fields["bar2"].child
        bar2_serializer.update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...

class FooWriteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    bar = ListField(
        child=BarWriteSerializer(),
        ...
        )
    def create(self, validated_date):
        ...
        bar_serializer = self.fields["bar"].child
        bar_serializer.create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_date):
        ...
        bar_serializer = self.fields["bar"].child
        bar_serializer.update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...
```

---edited---

```py
# views.py
class FooCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    ...

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().post(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do you mean the benefits of nested serializers as opposed to separate resources?

Comment: @NicoGriffioen yeap, you're right. Are there any other potential benefits than being able to seperate resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I use nested serializers when I want an interface where model B is always read (or created) together with model A. An example of this would be a `Pizza` model with a many-to-many relationship to `Topping`.

You'd want to separate these into two models to achieve a normalized database model, but retrieving a pizza's information without its toppings wouldn't make sense.

A 'create' example might be `UserCredentials` and `Profile`. You might want to separate these for security reasons, but it wouldn't make sense to create `UserCredentials` without an attached `Profile`.

The advantage here is a less complex interface. On the client-side, you don't need to do complex chained requests. (Retrieve pizza, then retrieve toppings every single time.) It also reduces overhead on the server, because there is only one request.

There are some disadvantages though. I tend to steer away from nested serializers because:

- When you also want to be able to retrieve/create these relationships separately, you'll need either two serializers, or one more complex serializer. This requires a lot of maintenance to keep everything working correctly.
- You might end up with multiple layers of nested serializers, which make it harder to separate your API into clearly defined resources.
- Performance is harder to control, because you can't apply pagination on the nested resource.

Comment: So on the server-side, there is no advantages of nested serializer if APIs are not seperated?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you don't separate the resources, you're going to need to use a nested serializer. So it's not really a question of advantages or disadvantages.

Comment: I mean, I'm wondering if there's any reason to use nested serializers. Although a single serializer can also handle non-seperated resources

Comment: A nested serializer does prevent code duplication, (Since you can reuse the serializer from the submodel)

Comment: Okay Thanks bro!!